# How to set the captured images using camera to fit into a Imageview of fixed height and width

Tags: android, android-camera

Hi i have followed android developer site and tried to implement capture an image from camera programatically. I am able to capture the image and set it in the ImageView.

But when I am setting the image into the ImageView i am getting an image of less width and height. Instead i want the image captured from gallery or camera should fit into the ImageView element layout. 
[image]

MyXML file is like as follows:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cmp_camera"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cmp_title"
            android:onClick="openCameraDialog"
            />
```

Since i have given the width as match_parent which is full screen I am getting less width.
My requirement is like it should fit the ImageView layout.
For camera coding I have followed this url:

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: use `scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: image1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Camera display / preview in full screen does not maintain aspect ratio - image is skewed, stretched in order to fit on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727836/camera-display-preview-in-full-screen-does-not-maintain-aspect-ratio-image-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

to your imageview inside xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try `imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

From XML, use this syntax: `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

The image is scaled using `Matrix.ScaleToFit FILL`, which performs the following:

> Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This may change the aspect ratio of the src.

See [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cmp_camera"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cmp_title"
        android:onClick="openCameraDialog"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to fit ur image and get rounded corner also

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = 19;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

And Set image to ImageView

```
 addimg.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(docode("Give path of your image here")));
```

Save image in sd card or phone memory, Decode it using its path.

```
 public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale++;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("decodeFile", "" + e);
    }

    return null;
}
```