# Full screen camera preview in portrait mode on Android 4.3

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, surfaceview, intelinde

I am using the Intel Inde library for media (specifically this example: https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile/blob/master/Android/samples/apps/src/com/intel/inde/mp/samples/CameraCapturerActivity.java)

My goal is to set up a full screen preview in portrait mode and record videos in portrait mode.  Everything works great in landscape mode(full screen preview and recording).  However in portrait mode I can't stretch the preview to fill the screen vertically (even though I set the surface view to max size).  The largest size I get is a square image preview.  I have tried making the surface view larger then the screen, but still stuck with a square preview and recording.

This is what my preview screen currently looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mNIb.jpg

Here is my code:

```
public void createCamera() 
{
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    List<Camera.Size> supportedResolutions = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(supportedResolutions.get(0).width,   
    supportedResolutions.get(0).height);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);  
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
}

public void createPreview() 
{
     GLSurfaceView surfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

     //This code is used to get display size to set surface view size
     Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
     Point size = new Point();
     display.getSize(size);
     int width = size.x;
     int height = size.y;

     surfaceView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));

     //Used to test that the surfaceview does cover the whole screen
     //surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

     ((RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.myview)).addView(surfaceView, 0);

     preview = capture.createPreview(surfaceView, camera);
     preview.start();           
 }
```

Comment: Do you want it to distort to fill the screen vertically, or retain the correct aspect ratio?

Comment: I would like the correct aspect ratio and fill vertically (similar if I use the default camera app and get a full screen undistorted preview)

Answer (score 1):

There is a thread on the Intel Developer site, appears to be the same issue.  They have a solution, but you have to request the library update via email:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/542633

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are setting the preview size of your camera to the **first** size in the list of supported sizes.

```
List<Camera.Size> supportedResolutions = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
parameters.setPreviewSize(supportedResolutions.get(0).width, supportedResolutions.get(0).height);
```

What you should do is loop through the list of supported sizes and find a size that closely matches the screen's size/resolution.

You can check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16733405/2688283) for sample code snippets

**Update**

The next step would be to debug it and find out why it didn't work for you. What I would do in your case would be to print out the contents of the `supportedResolutions` list. Since you already the have the display size, I would compare the display size to the different sizes in the `supportedResolutions` list and also to the size returned from the `getOptimalSize` method. It's possible that the `getOptimalSize` method didn't find an optimal size and the method may need to be tweaked to your need. I tweaked mine to get it to work.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: iRuth, I've implemented the getOptimalSize() method from the SO answer you mentioned, and the result is still the same.  No difference :(

Comment: I'm debugging on an HTC one if that makes any difference.  I added some debug lines, and can confirm that getOptimalSize does return a valid size(1920x1088).  Are you getting a full screen preview in portrait mode?

Comment: Yes I did get a full screen preview in portrait mode.

Comment: Are you using a GLSurfaceView, or something else?  Do you mind sharing your code?  Maybe I missed something.

Comment: @nyc0202034 No, I am using `SurfaceView` but I don't think that should matter. What is the size returned by `display` in your `createPreview` method?

Comment: I get a display size of 1920x1080 (phone's resolution)

Comment: That's odd. Can you try swapping the width and the height for the `GLSurfaceView` and/or camera and see if that changes anything?