# Android Camera2 preview is stretching

Tags: android, camera2

I'm using Camera2 but the preview is stretching. Please help me.I have uploaded images please check. I'm new to android.

[From Camera Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H32oh.jpg)
[From Camera Code I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YuB4.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I'm using this code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ee699a6/tests/Camera2Tests/CameraToo/src/com/example/android/camera2/cameratoo/CameraTooActivity.java

Comment: what is `Size optimalSize`?

Comment: Hi, I don't know, I'm bit new to this API. I think that's the PreviewSize as per the Device

Comment: so check your sources what it is used for

Comment: Well I'm trying the source sir.

Comment: please take a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43516672/7334112
this would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the official sample apps from Google, such as [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic), or the new [CameraView](https://github.com/google/cameraview) library.  They handle aspect ratio issues such as what you're seeing.

**Edit:**

As of 2023, I'd recommend looking at the CameraX [CameraViewfinder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/viewfinder/CameraViewfinder) class if you're wanting to use camera2 directly. It handles picking between TextureView and SurfaceView based on API level and device quirks, and deals with aspect ratios and rotations correctly.

If you're using CameraX for the whole camera experience, then the CameraX [PreviewView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView) is even simpler to use.

Comment: Yes, CameraView is working well. I have been testing CameraView on Android 4.4, Android 5.1 and Android 7.0.

Comment: Actually, the aspect ratio [bug](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/issues/69) in Camera2Basic [was fixed](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/pull/83) after this answer was posted.

Comment: The sample apps don't build for me and CameraView is deprecated :(