# Camera is stretched on Android version 8.1.0 and 9.0 - Android Camera2 API

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2, aspect-ratio

Hi I am using Camera 2 API in Android for image capture of ID cards, In certain Android version likes 8.1.0 and 9.o the camera view is stretched and items looks longer and slimmer then they should be.

I tried to add padding top bottom of 70dp to root_view layout, that kind of makes it better, but I am sure that is not a correct way.

Can you suggest on what I should be doing please.

Original image using camera
[image: Image using the original device camera app]
Screenshot of the image through the app using camera 2 api
[image: Image using camera2 api]

Here is my XML file in which I am displaying the camera.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:clickable="true">

<TextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_toolbar_height"
    android:paddingTop="24dp"
    android:background="#99000000">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/take_photo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        style="@style/ScreenTitleStyle"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<View
    android:id="@+id/photo_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="212dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_photo_frame"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/double_padding"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/take_picture_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#99000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/take_photo_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:letterSpacing="-0.02"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="9sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        style="@style/OpenSansMedium"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/take_picture_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_capture"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/approve_picture_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/check_photo_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:letterSpacing="-0.02"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="9sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        style="@style/OpenSansMedium"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="21dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/retake_picture"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_login_button"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:text="@string/retake_button"
            style="@style/LoginButtonStyle"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/use_picture"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_login_button"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/blueyPurple"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/use_button"
            style="@style/LoginButtonStyle"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/transparentWhite"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my .java file which handles the camera2

onresume -

> textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);

```
TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        //open your camera here
        textureViewWidth = width;
        textureViewHeight = height;
        openCamera();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        // Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    }
};

private void openCamera() {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
    try {
        cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        assert map != null;
        imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
        // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }
        manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
}

private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
        //This is called when the camera is open
        Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
        cameraDevice = camera;
        createCameraPreview();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
        cameraDevice.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        cameraDevice = null;
    }
};

protected void createCameraPreview() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                //The camera is already closed
                if (null == cameraDevice) {
                    return;
                }
                // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                updatePreview();
                Log.e(TAG, "createCaptureSession -  onConfigured");
            }
            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                //Toast.makeText(TakePhotoFragmentCamera2.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "createCaptureSession -  onConfigureFailed");
            }
        }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void updatePreview() {
    if(null == cameraDevice) {
        Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
    }
    //captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    //captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
    try {
        cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [AutoFitTextureView.java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37435200/192373).

Comment: @BRDroid AutoFitTextureView resolved your issue ?