# I want to record video in Landscape mode no matter device orientation is portrait or landscape

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am using Media Recorder for recording ,Can Anyone has idea how can to apply Logic?
Right now Video  recording is happening in Landscape always but it doesn't capturing right orientation ,screen also get rotated

```
private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
                                       Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result = null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = size;
            } else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                if (newArea > resultArea) {
                    result = size;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (result);
}
```

Comment: What issue are you using? Also check that _auto rotation_ must be enabled in your device.

Comment: I know about auto rotation ,my issue is when i am trying to capture in horizontal view i am not getting proper measures so my view is stretching while capture is ongoing .I have used  , I  have used below method for getting proper with and height  .

Comment: Then you have to maintain the aspect ratio for it

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434494/android-camera-2-preview-size-and-devices-aspect-ratio)?

Comment: Thanks ,I will check it out ,I am afraid, it does not work for me

Comment: It will be worked. Are you using Camera2 API?

Comment: Nope I haven't.

Comment: Are you using it for record video ?

Comment: no i am using normal camera object for it not Camera2

Comment: But if you are using custom camera then you should use _Camera2_ API

Comment: okay i will try if it helps with current issue,but it only works from api level 21 and i have to manage it for api level 18

Comment: There is github code which supports lower version too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195573/discussion-between-richa-shah-and-piyush).

Answer (score 1):

Check [setRotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29) method of camera parameter. If you don't use this one then you can try with `mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(rotation)`(only changes the orientation of the output video, not the orientation of the preview if you want to forcefully preview to landscape then `Camera.setDisplayOrientation(rotation)`) while recording your video.